Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code while archiving a react native project using xcode
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/codersmacbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kno-eupnigjpqbdtmadvbnjydjuziuaa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kno/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Kno.build/Release-iphoneos/Kno.build/Script-410FCBE3682CBCE516718EE6.sh (in target 'Kno' from project 'Kno')
    cd /Users/codersmacbook/Downloads/app/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/codersmacbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kno-eupnigjpqbdtmadvbnjydjuziuaa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kno/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Kno.build/Release-iphoneos/Kno.build/Script-410FCBE3682CBCE516718EE6.sh

mkdir -p /Users/codersmacbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kno-eupnigjpqbdtmadvbnjydjuziuaa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kno/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Kno.app/Frameworks
/Users/codersmacbook/Downloads/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Kno/Pods-Kno-frameworks.sh: line 42: source: unbound variable
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
I'm trying to archiving ipa file for iOS of my React Native Project.
